# next/previous page from an array of page id's

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an array of page ID's which I need to use to create a simple next/previous page menu.

Below you can see what I have put together so far.

I realize I am not even close here...

```
    <?php
        $pagelist = array(0,1358,226,1394,1402,1468,0);

        $prevID = prev($pagelist);
        $nextID = next($pagelist);
    ?>

    <div class="navigation">
        <?php if ($prevID != 0) { ?>
        <div class="alignleft">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prevID); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($prevID); ?>">Previous</a>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($nextID != 0) { ?>
        <div class="alignright">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextID); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($nextID); ?>">Next</a>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div><!-- .navigation -->
```

I think I need to use the current page ID at some point which I get using this function

```
<?php the_ID(); ?>
```

Could anybody help point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming that your URL contain id parameter :

```
<?php
        $pagelist = array(0,1358,226,1394,1402,1468,0);

        $currentIndex = array_search($_GET['id'], $pagelist); // $_GET['id'] may be replace by your the_ID() function

        $prevID = $currentIndex - 1 < 0 ? $pagelist[0] : $pagelist[$currentIndex - 1];
        $nextID = $currentIndex + 1 > count($pagelist)-1 ? $pagelist[count($pagelist)-1] : $pagelist[$currentIndex + 1];
    ?>

    <div class="navigation">
        <?php if ($prevID != 0) { ?>
        <div class="alignleft">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prevID); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($prevID); ?>">Previous</a>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($nextID != 0) { ?>
        <div class="alignright">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextID); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($nextID); ?>">Next</a>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div><!-- .navigation -->
```

Hope this solution may help you

Comment: Thank you for simple solution!